# How to find maximum area among given triangles on C++

Tags: c++, math, geometry, max, area

The input should be n - the number of triangles (1 <= n <= 20) and afterwards n rows of three doubles each (corresponding to each of the triangles' sides). The output should be the "n" which has the maximum triangle area.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20;

int main()
{
    int n, s, p;
    double max = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int x[MAX_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double y[2];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cin >> y[j];
        p = (y[0] + y[1] + y[2]) / 2;
        s = sqrt(p * (p - y[0]) * (p - y[1]) * (p - y[3]));
        if (s >= max) max = s;
    }
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

That's what I've done so far. "p" stands for semiparameter by the way.. - I'm using Heron's formula. I haven't even got it to "cout" the n in which the area is max but rather the maximum area itself, yet it doesn't work but gives me a massive error instead. Any ideas?

Comment: **First** write code that calculates the area of a triangle, and write code that can find the maximum in a sequence. *When both of those parts are working perfectly,* **then** combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

- You need to change `s` and `p` from `int`s to `double`s (otherwise you'll get unwanted truncation of your results).
- You need to change `double y[2];` to `double y[3];` (since you need three side lengths, not two).
- Change `s = sqrt(p * (p - y[0]) * (p - y[1]) * (p - y[3]));` to `s = sqrt(p * (p - y[0]) * (p - y[1]) * (p - y[2]));` (since `y[3]` is out of bounds of your array).

Note also that you can get rid of your array `x`, since you don't seem to actually use it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I answered to my thread referring to a new problem. Could you help me out? I'm commenting on this as I don't know whether you get a notification for my answer or not. I'm kinda new here.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocation only 2 doubles. You need 3, try `double y[3]`.